# Python list error for count vectorizer and fit function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Please tell what is wrong and how to rectify.

```
data = open(r"C:\Users\HS\Desktop\WORK\R\R DATA\g textonly2.txt").read()
labels, texts = [], []
#print(data)
for i, line in enumerate(data.split("\n")):
    content = line.split()
    #print(content)
    if len(content) is not 0:
        labels.append(content[0])
        texts.append(content[1:])


# create a dataframe using texts and lables
trainDF = pandas.DataFrame()
trainDF['text'] = texts
trainDF['label'] = labels

# split the dataset into training and validation datasets
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(trainDF['text'], trainDF['label'])

# label encode the target variable
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
train_y = encoder.fit_transform(train_y)
valid_y = encoder.fit_transform(valid_y)

# create a count vectorizer object
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
count_vect.fit(trainDF['text'])
```

The data file contains data like this:

```
0 #\xdaltimahora Es tracta d'un aparell de Germanwings amb 152 passatgers a bord
0 Route map now being shared by http:
0 Pray for #4U9525 http:
0 Airbus A320 #4U9525 crash: \nFlight tracking data here: \nhttp
```

Error:

```
Traceback:
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "C:/Users/HS/PycharmProjects/R/C/Text classification1.py"
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HS/PycharmProjects/R/C/Text classification1.py", line 38, in <module>
    count_vect.fit(trainDF['text'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 836, in fit
    self.fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 869, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 232, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit):

> fit(raw_documents, y=None)[source] Learn a vocabulary dictionary of
>   all tokens in the raw documents.
>
> Parameters:    raw_documents : iterable
>
> An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.
>
> Returns:   self :

You get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` because you gave it an iterable (in this case a `pd.Series`) of list objects, instead of an iterable of strings.

You should be able to fix this by using `texts.append(' '.join(content[1:]))`
instead of `texts.append(content[1:])`:

```
for i, line in enumerate(data.split("\n")):
    content = line.split()
    #print(content)
    if len(content) is not 0:
        labels.append(content[0])
        #texts.append(content[1:])
        texts.append(' '.join(content[1:]))
```

Comment: Perfect, glad it worked @Harshita! Could you do me a favor and accept the answer then?

Comment: Sorry, did not know about this thing. I have accepted now. I have another question regarding SwarmPackage library of Python. Please have a look.

Comment: Oh, no worries - I don't think I can help you with that, had a look!